# How to get into an Excel Spreadsheet when it's crashing upon opening it due to in-correct VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to excel and trying to add a VBA Code to create an email distribution list but when I added it, it crashed the spreadsheet and now every time I load the report it's crashing before I can get in and the older version is doing the same, is there a way I can get in and remove the code I added without opening it and crashing it again? Thanks, Allie

Comment: I'm guessing you have the code in a `Workbook_Open` event (or similar). Open a blank, new Excel workbook, go to Tools -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings -> Disable all macros.  That way Excel will ignore all macros so you can go in and edit your code.  Then you can turn macros back on and try again.

Comment: Hold down Shift while opening the file (if the issue is a bad Workbook_Open macro).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new workbook and in it have a macro that simply issues an

`Application.EnableEvents=False`.

Then open the problem workbook within the same instance of Excel.

Nothing automatic can kill you and you can still debug the *VBA*.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help :) Greatly appreciated!